# Find the general solution for: $x\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{4-y^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution for: $$x\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{4-y^2}$$

I solved this to get: $$y=2\sin(\ln|x|)$$

But when I graph the function: $$f(x)=2\sin(\ln|x|)$$

and its slope function: $$\frac{dy}{dx}(x)=\frac{\sqrt{4-(2\sin(\ln|x|))^2}}{x}$$

something doesn't match up. The function $f(x)$ has negative slopes at certain locations but the slope function has no negative values. The slope function seems to be the absolute value function of the slope function. Have I made an error somewhere?

Comment: The solution of ODE is $f(x)=2\sin(\ln |x|)+c).$ Also we have local existence but not existence on $\mathbb{R}$ or $(0,\infty)$ in general. Well, in this case, $y=\pm 2$ are solutions defined on $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @RayDansh You repeated what I said but didn't explain anything. Do you think my solution is correct or not ? Graphically the solution in not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\arcsin  \frac  y2 = \ln |x| + C$

$C$ needs to be suitable for your initial conditions, such that $-\pi <\ln |x| + C <\pi$

And over some range of $x, y(x)$ is valid.

And when $-\pi <\ln |x| + C <\pi$ moves out of this range, something going to break.

If x crosses $0$ something bad is going to happen, and for some $x, y(x)$ will equal $2$ at which point $y$ becomes a constant function.